# SCNNodes disappear after zooming out in Scene Kit?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am attempting to generate a 3d voxel style island and am generating bricks and placing them on the scene. However, when I set the z axis on the camera node to more than 150, objects disappear behind the white background.

```
import Cocoa
import SceneKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = SCNView()
let scene = SCNScene()
view.scene = scene
view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 650, height: 650)

public func buildIsland(size: Int, image: NSImage, scene: SCNScene){

//Start building the island
var blocks = 0
for x in 0...size {
    for y in 0...size {

        //Create Block
        var block = SCNBox(width: 10, height: 10, length: 10, chamferRadius: 0)
        var color = SCNMaterial()
        color.diffuse.contents = CGColor.init(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        block.materials[0] = color
        var node = SCNNode(geometry: block)
        node.position = SCNVector3(x/2, y/2, 0)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        blocks = blocks + 1

    }
}

}




view.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
var cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 200)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

buildIsland(size: 4, image: NSImage(), scene: scene)

view.allowsCameraControl = true

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Configure the `zFar` property of the camera to avoid clipping when the camera is further away. (The default value is 100)

For example:
`cameraNode.camera?.zFar = 500`

You can play with this property to get everything visible while trying to keep good performance.